# Weird, unused chat room showing up

Tags: discussion, support

On the right-side menu of the main and meta sites, the list of chat rooms include an unused, weirdly-named room. I'm afraid it not of much used on the main page, and can even be confusing to users:

> [image: Screenshot]

Could this be removed from the list (or the chat room closed, if it's unused)? What's the procedure for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The room poses no risk. It looks to me like somebody setting some kind of code/cypher challenge. Please let me know if people think this is on-topic/off-topic; if the latter (which is my guess), I'll kill it.

Edit: as the owner isn't active on English, I'm killing it.

Answer (score 3):

(The room was called "Leet Speak", as written in [Leet Speak.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet_speak))

Comment: That is *so* last century. What is this, 1998? :)